# How to access list item and filter it?

Tags: python

I have three lists differentiate by header, condition and parameter:

```
header = [("'header1 : Subject', 'header2 :Text'",), ("'header1 : Subject'",)]
condition = [("'condition1 : Equal', 'condition2: Contain'",), ("'condition1: Contain'",)]
parameter = [("'parameter1: hi1', 'parameter2: hi2'}",), ("'parameter1: haha'",)]
```

What i trying to achieve here is to make the first item in each list to match with the first item in the both lists. For example: header1's `Subject` , condition1's `Equal` , parameter1's `hi1` is in the same data.

Expected Output:

```
data1 = Subject Equal hi1
data2 = Text Contain hi2
data3 = Subject Contain haha
```

After get all this data, how can i filter it by header , condition and parameter ?

This is my code idea :

```
 if 'header' == 'Subject' or 'Text':
      if 'condition' == 'Equal':
          print(parameter)
      if 'condition' == 'Contain':
           print(parameter)
```

Expected Output (demo):

It will read the first data which is `Subject Equal hi1` and go through my function and determine the header is `Subject` or `Text` then determine again it's `Equal` or `Contain`  then only print the specific parameter which in this case is `hi1`.

Comment: The input data is in bad shape. It needs to be in a dict atleast.

Comment: Why not have header3 instead of header1?

Comment: @DevangSanghani the header1,2,3.. and so on is based on data user input. The header(index) will be added dynamically if there is new input by user

Comment: @DevangSanghani There is a new header1 instead of header3 is because its a new user input by a new user. Thats mean when there are third person input a new data, it will again seperate like this `("'header1 : Subject', 'header2 :Text'",), ("'header1 : Subject'",) ,  ("'header1 : Text'",)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
import re

re_value = re.compile(r":\s*(\w+)'")

result = [
    tuple(re_value.search(string)[1] for string in values)
    for (h,), (c,), (p,) in zip(header, condition, parameter)
    for values in zip(h.split(","), c.split(","), p.split(","))
]
```

or

```
result = [
    tuple(string.split(":")[1].split("'")[0].strip() for string in values)
    for (h,), (c,), (p,) in zip(header, condition, parameter)
    for values in zip(h.split(","), c.split(","), p.split(","))
]
```

if you don't like the regex.

Result:

```
[('Subject', 'Equal', 'hi1'), ('Text', 'Contain', 'hi2'), ('Subject', 'Contain', 'haha')]
```

If you want to loop over it a generator might be more appropriate:

```
result = (
    tuple(string.split(":")[1].split("'")[0].strip() for string in values)
    for (h,), (c,), (p,) in zip(header, condition, parameter)
    for values in zip(h.split(","), c.split(","), p.split(","))
)
for head, cond, param in result:
    print(head, cond, param)
```

---

Edit: After revisiting the question I think I like this destructuring better, seems more generic:

```
result = [
    tuple(re_value.search(string)[1] for string in strings)
    for tuples in zip(header, condition, parameter)
    for strings in zip(*(tup[0].split(",") for tup in tuples))
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is very close to my objective. But how can i access each tuple's item? For example, i need to get the `Subject`.

Comment: @WEIZHUANGGOH Not sure I understand, maybe my edit helps.

Answer (score 1):

Changed the input to dicts.

```
header = [{'header1' : 'Subject', 'header2' :'Text'}, {'header3' : 'Subject'}]
condition = [{'condition1': 'Equal','condition2': 'Contain'}, {'condition3': 'Contain'}]
parameter = [{'parameter1': 'hi1', 'parameter2': 'hi2'}, {'parameter1': 'haha'}]
    
h1 = header[0]['header1']   
c1 = condition[0]['condition1']
p1 = parameter[0]['parameter1']

data1 = h1,c1,p1
print(data1)
```

You can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it should print all the header,condition and parameter and not just specific header1,condition1,parameter1 only